# Generating user id based on some input values

Tags: javascript

I came across this question on [Mettl](https://mettl.com/) :

The function takes four parameters -

1. first name(String)
2. last name(String)
3. pin(int) : a number that contains digits of any length

   eg: 1234,34565789
4. number(int) : a number(1-9 both inclusive and less than the length of the pin) that determines the number of digits that has to be used for the generation of id, from the beginning and the end of the pin entered above.

Conditions for generating the id are:

1. the name with smaller length is taken as the small name and the name with bigger length is taken as large name.
2. if the lengths of both the first and last name are equal, then the name occurring alphabetically first is taken as the small name.
3. the number for the generation is obtained using the 'number' and 'pin' inputs.
4. after the id is generated the letters are toggled,i.e the lowercase letters are changed to uppercase and vice-versa.

Example 1:

first name: Rajiv

last name: Roy

pin: 123456

number: 3

Here 'Roy' is smaller in length than 'Rajiv'. So 'Roy' becomes the small name and 'Rajiv' becomes the large name. The 3rd digit from starting of the pin is '3' and the 3rd digit from the end of the pin is '4'. Therefore the number generated is 34.

The last letter of smaller name is 'y'. So the id generated is yRajiv34.

After toggling the letters, the final id generated is YrAJIV34.

```js
function generateId(firstName, lastName, pin, n) {
    var result = '';
    var smallName = '';
    var largeName = '';
    if (firstName.length != lastName.length) {
        if (firstName.length < lastName.length) {
            smallName = firstName;
            largeName = lastName;
        } else {
            largeName = firstName;
            smallName = lastName;
        }

    } else {
        var names = [firstName.toLowerCase(), lastName.toLowerCase()];
        var sorted = names.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a > b;
        });
        smallName = sorted[0];
        largeName = sorted[1];
    }

    result += smallName.substr(smallName.length - 1, 1).toUpperCase();
    result += largeName.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + largeName.substr(1, largeName.length).toUpperCase();

    var pinString = pin.toString();
    var numberLength = pinString.length;

    result += pinString.charAt(n - 1) + pinString.charAt(numberLength - n);

    return result;
}

var x = generateId('Kumar', 'Kumud', 530076, 2);
console.log(x);

var y = generateId('Rajiv', 'Roy', 345678, 3);
console.log(y);
```

## problem:

its working well for all the test cases I pass and even got 7/10 test cases correct in the mettl site. I don't know what the reason is for the failure of the remaining 3 test cases. Is there a way to improve the algorithm or anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the procedure to generate the id ? You just mentioned the condtions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not toggling the characters, you are just assuming that first character of the string will be uppercase and making it lower case and all other characters will be in lower case and making them uppercase.
This won't work for cases such as:

```
generateId('RajIV', 'Roy', 345678, 6); // YrAJIV83
```

Also you are not handling the case where `number` is greater than the length of `pin`. It still gives an output.

```
generateId('RajIV', 'Roy', 345678, 7); // YrAJIV
```